# SQL Query for retrieving data fro same colum twice

Tags: oracle

Query:

Display employee number, name, manager number, manager name for all the employees.

Table `EMP`

```
Name                            Type            Constraints
------------------------------- -------- ----
 EMPNO                         NUMBER(4)    Primary Key
 ENAME                         VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                               VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                             NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                   DATE
 SAL                               NUMBER(7,2)  Must be greater then ZERO
 COMM                          NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                      NUMBER(2)      Foreign Key dept(deptno)
```

Sample data:

```
EMPNO   ENAME   JOB MGR HIREDATE    SAL COMM    DEPTNO
7369    SMITH   CLERK   7902    17-DEC-80   800     20
7499    ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-FEB-81   1600    300 30
7521    WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-FEB-81   1250    500 30
7566    JONES   MANAGER 7839    02-APR-81   2975        20
7654    MARTIN  SALESMAN    7698    28-SEP-81   1250    1400    30
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 7839    01-MAY-81   2850        30
7782    CLARK   MANAGER 7839    09-JUN-81   2450        10
7788    SCOTT   ANALYST 7566    09-DEC-82   3000        20
7839    KING    PRESIDENT       17-NOV-81   5000        10
7844    TURNER  SALESMAN    7698    08-SEP-81   1500    0   30
7876    ADAMS   CLERK   7788    12-JAN-83   1100        20
7900    JAMES   CLERK   7698    03-DEC-81   950     30
7902    FORD    ANALYST 7566    03-DEC-81   3000        20
7934    MILLER  CLERK   7782    23-JAN-82   1300        10
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn the basics first.

In this SQL, you need to first self join the table. Because, Manager himself is an employee with the manager id.

But ultimately, one employee will be at TOP, and he don't have an manager, so we have make a OUTER join here.. INNER JOIN would fetch all the qualified records, but with a outer join, we just take the matched records.

```
SELECT E1.EMPNO,
       E1.ENAME,
       E2.EMPNO AS MANAGER_NUMBER,
       E2.ENAME AS MANAGER_NAME
FROM EMP E1
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMP E2 
ON (E1.MGR = E2.EMPNO)
```